# Keyword iterator

Tags: javascript, strings

I want to read through a "string" once and only once, and `charAt` doesn't do that, does it? If there was some sort of optimized nextChar feature, I'd be thrilled. What I'm picturing in my head resembles the jet speed velocity of DNA replication, all six feet of it per cell. And don't forget RNA and all the other critter instructions in there, too, dividing as we speak. It took 39 generations of teaching fruit flies how to count before counting became instinctual, but the genetic programming finally stuck.

In the early 1990s I was tasked to update our code base to handle multi-byte character sets, which meant racing through null terminated character arrays with pointers. On another occasion I was to lift Microsoft's CString for our own use. I remember CString contained an undocumented function call, and their internal parsing of multi-byte strings was not something in the examples provided.

In the mid-2000s while developing an iterator, I noticed `charAt` had a significant amount of 5ms lags that really slowed things down, so I `split` the string into an array, but that means going over the string more than once, even though something like `array.map` might be just what I need.

To that extent, I'm trying to create a keyword iterator that accepts a string as well as an array of strings, and to basically process everything as it comes in bit by bit. Is that even possible in JavaScript?

```
function KeywordIterator(keyword) {
  if (typeof keyword === "string") {
    this._remaining = keyword.length;
    this.character = function() { return keyword.charAt(this._current); };
  } else if (typeof keyword === "number") {
    keyword = keyword.toString();
    this._remaining = keyword.length;
    this.character = function() { return keyword.charAt(this._current); };
  } else if (Array.isArray(keyword)) {
    this._remaining = keyword.length;
    this.character = function() { return keyword[this._current]; };
    this.isArray = true;
  } else {
    this._remaining = 0;
    this.character = function() { return ""; };
  }
}

KeywordIterator.prototype = {
  constructor: KeywordIterator,
  _current: 0,
  inside: function() { return (this._remaining > 0); },
  //character() returns string at _current index
  next: function() { this._current++; --this._remaining; },
  forEach: function(callback,thisp) {
    while (this._remaining > 0) {
      callback.call(thisp,this.character());
      this._current++; --this._remaining;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) - you can get a built-in iterator as follows: `var iterator = arrayOrString[Symbol.iterator](); var first = iterator.next().value;`. Also see the for-of loop: `for (var char of string) { ... }`. To convert string to chars, you can also do `var chars = [...string];`.

Comment: @le_m you could expand a bit on your comment and make it an answer

Comment: Ugh! Flashbacks to (multiplier times sizeof struct)

Answer (score 1):

#### Garbage in, garbage out

When `KeywordIterator` receives something it cannot handle,
it quietly returns an empty iterator.
It would be better to crash with a big bang so the caller notices the problem early.

#### One statement per line

Usually it's recommended to write one statement per line,
because it's easier to read from top to bottom,
and it's less risky to miss something important in the middle of lines.

#### Interface design

The `inside` function is not used in the posted code,
and I'm not sure about its purpose.
The same goes for `isArray`.

When talking about iterators,
I would expect that a function called `next` would return the next element.
That's not the case here,
which could be considered confusing.

If some functions are not intended to be used from outside the implementation,
it would be good to make them private, inaccessible.